# Maximum voltages of an op amp comparator

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, comparator

If I have an op amp setup as a comparator, e.g. like this one:

[image]

I know that Vo represents the difference in the input voltages, but is there a maximum value these voltages can be? Is there a limit to Vo, V1, and V2?

Comment: Look in the opamp datasheet for maximum values.

Comment: Many tutorials on web. Theoretical ideal opamp has infinite gain. Vout is divided by a factor of N and fed back to opamp-inputs so as to oppose Vin so that average at input of opamp is zero. When Vout/Vin = N opamp sees zero opamp-input. As Vin changes the opamp will produce a change to bring opamp-input back to zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, if I understand correctly what you ask, Vo is NOT the difference between the two inputs. Usually, a comparator works this way:

If V1 > V2, Vo is equal approximately to +Vcc-0,7V.

If V1 < V2, Vo is equal approximately to -Vcc+0,7V.

(usually stated in the datasheet).

So, it is a comparison (greater than or lesser than) between the two inputs. Vo is more of an indicator of which case is present.

For the values of V1, V2, +Vcc, -Vcc, etc., they are normally stated in the datasheet since some comparator may have different specs.

If you don't know how to read/find a datasheet, if you have a part number maybe we could help you with this too.

Hope it will help you!

Comment: Well this is just a general question. I'm trying to understand how op amps work and all of the different types.

Comment: Some of them can be supplied with a wide range of +Vcc and -Vcc. Some of them accept a -Vcc of 0V (Circuit ground), which is useful if you don't have a negative supply. Just don't forget that normally, the output does not supply/source a lot of current, i.e. it is usually not possible to power something with the output of an op amp/ comparator.

Comment: Generally, the inputs of op-amps and comparators (and most other ICs, for that matter) must remain between the supply rails.  Comparator outputs are normally open collector - an NPN transistor with its emitter grounded, or connected to the negative supply, and no internal connection to the collector.  You need to supply an external pull-up resistor to see a high level on the output.  Usually, the pull-up voltage must not be higher than the positive supply (but some parts do allow higher voltages).

Answer (score 4):

Refer to this literature from

- Texas Instruments, [Understanding Op Amp Parameters](http://www.ti.com/lit/ml/sloa083/sloa083.pdf)
- Analog Devices, [MT-041: Op Amp Input and Output Common-Mode and
  Differential Voltage Range](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/tutorials/MT-041.pdf)

#### Input Common Mode Voltage Range

> The input common voltage is defined as the average voltage at the inverting and non inverting input pins. If the common mode voltage gets too high or too low, the inputs will shut down and proper operation ceases. The common mode input voltage range, \$V_{ICR}\$, specifies the range over which normal operation is guaranteed.
> [image]
> [image source](http://www.planetanalog.com/document.asp?doc_id=528175)
> For voltage followers, inverting, and non-inverting configuration it is commonly assumed that \$V_{IN+}\$ equals \$V_{IN-}\$ equals \$V_{ICM}\$, since these voltages are approximately the same.

#### Differential Input Voltage Range

> Differential input voltage range is normally specified as an absolute maximum. Exceeding the differential input voltage range can lead to breakdown and part failure.
>
> In normal operation, an op amp has the feedback loop connected; therefore the differential input voltage is held at zero volts  (neglecting the offset voltage). However under certain conditions, such as power-up, the op amp may be subjected to a differential input voltage which is not zero. Certain input structures require limiting of differential input voltage to prevent damage. These opamps will generally have internal back-to-back diodes across the inputs. This will not always show up in the simplified schematics of the amps. It will show up, however, as a differential input voltage specification of  ±700 mV maximum.

#### Maximum Output Voltage Swing

> The maximum output voltage, \$V_{OM±}\$, is defined as  the maximum positive or negative peak output voltage that can be obtained without wave form clipping, when quiescent DC output voltage is zero. \$V_{OM±} \$ is limited by the output impedance of the amplifier, the saturation voltage of the output transistors, and the power supply voltages. This is shown pictorially in the next image
> [image]
> [image source](http://www.ti.com/lit/ml/sloa083/sloa083.pdf)

---

Regarding the use of an opamp as a comparator, refer to this literature from Texas Instruments:
[Op Amp and Comparators – Don’t Confuse Them!](http://encon.fke.utm.my/nikd/latest/sloa067.pdf)